# Invoking ZSH commands from Java/Groovy Process

Tags: java, groovy, zsh

Running the following Groovy code is giving me error `: unmatched '`

`Process process = "zsh -c 'ls -l'".execute()`

However, the following works fine `Process process = "zsh -c ls".execute()`.

How to invoke a zsh command which takes multiple flags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never *ever* use `String.execute()` - it will split on whitespace and is only sane for very simple commands. The attempt in quoting is in vain in any case, because no shell is used here to parse the string.

Always use `List.execute()` instead.  E.g.

```
["zsh", "-c", "ls -1"].execute()
```